# how to properly create my own custom items and triggers for zabbix 4

Tags: postgresql, zabbix

:)

I have Zabbix 4.4.1 installed on Ubuntu 19.10.

I have a postgresql plugin configured and working properly so it checks my database metrics.

I have a a table that I want to check a timestamp column for the last inserted row. column name is `insert_time`.

if the last inserted row have a insert time of more then 5 minutes to product warning and 10 minutes to product error.

I'm new to zabbix.. all I did so far is for googling, not sure if that's the way to go.. it's probably not cause it's not working :)

ok so first thing I did is created a bash files at `/etc/zabbix/mytools`, `get-last-insert-time.sh`.

I perform the query and send the output to zabbix_sender with the following template:

```
#!/bin/bash
PGPASSWORD=<PASSWORD> -U <USER> <DB> -t -c "<RELEVANT QUERY>" | awk '{$1=$1};1' | tr -d "\n" | xargs -I {} /usr/bin/zabbix_sender -z $ZABBIXSERVER -p $ZABBIXPORT  -s $ZABBIXAGENT -k "my.pgsql.cdr.last_insert_time" -o {}
```

is there a way to test this step? how can I make sure that zabbix_sender receives that information? is there some kind of.. zabbix_sender_sniffer of some sort ? :)

next.. I created a configuration files at /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.d called `get-last-insert-time.conf` with the following template:

```
UserParameter=my_pgsql_cdr_last_insert_time,/etc/zabbix/mytools/get-last-insert-time.sh;echo $?
```

here the key is `my_pgsql_cdr_last_insert_time` while the key in zabbix_sender is `my.pgsql.cdr.last_insert_time`. as far as I understand these should be two different keys.

why?!

then I created a template and attached it to the relevant host and I created 2 items for it:

1. item for insert time with the key `my.pgsql.cdr.last_insert_time` and of type `Zabbix Trapper`
2. a `Zabbix Agent` item with the key `my_pgsql_cdr_last_insert_time` Type of information: text.

is that the type of information for timestamp ?

now on `Overview` -> `latest data` I see:

`CDR last insert time` with no data
and  `Run my database trappers insert time` that is... the text is disabled? it's in gray.. and there is also no data.

so before I begin to create an alert. what did I do wrong ?

any information regarding this issue would be greatly appreciated.

## update

thanks Jan Garaj for this valuable information.
I was expecting that creating such a trigger should be easier then what I found on google, glad to see I was correct.

I edited my bash scripts to return seconds since epoch, since it's from postgresql it returns float, so I configured the items as float. I do see in `latest data` that the items receive the proper values.

I created triggers, I made sure that the warning trigger depends on the critical trigger so they won't both appear on the same time.

for example I created this trigger `{cdrs:pgsql.cdr.last_insert_time.fuzzytime(300)}=0` so if the last insert time is greater then 5 minutes to return a critical error. the problem is that it returns a critical error.. always! even when it shouldn't. I couldn't find a way to debug this. so besides actually getting the triggers to work properly everything else is well configured.

any ideas ?

## update 2

when I configured the script to return a timestamp, I changed it to a different timezone instead of living it as it is, which actually compared the data with current time + 2 hours in the future :)

I found that out while going to latest data, checking the timestamp and converting it to actual time. so everything works now thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks over complicated, because you are mixing sender with agent approach. Simpler approach - agent only:

```
UserParameter=pgsql.cdr.last_insert_time,/etc/zabbix/mytools/get-last-insert-time.sh
```

Script `/etc/zabbix/mytools/get-last-insert-time.sh` returns last insert Unix timestamp only, e.g.`1574111464` (no new line and don't use zabbix_sender in the script). Keep in mind, that zabbix agent uses `zabbix` user usually, so you need to configure proper script (exec) permissions, eventually env variables.

Test it with `zabbix-get` from the Zabbix server, e.g.:

```
zabbix_get -s <HOST IP> -p 10050 -k "pgsql.cdr.last_insert_time"
```

For any issue on the agent side: increase log agent level and watch agent logs

When you sort agent part, then create template with item key `pgsql.cdr.last_insert_time` and `Numeric (unsigned)` type. Trigger can use [`fuzzytime(60)` function](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.4/manual/appendix/triggers/functions).